# How can I prevent javascript from submitting a form on a script error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I am trying to debug a javascript problem, but the problem happens when submitting a form. I see a javascript error briefly in the console window, then the form gets submitted.

Is there a way to make the default not to submit the form, so I can see the script error before I get sent to the form submit page?

The code is using jquery with a

```
$('#form').on('submit', function() {
    // validation code with script error somewhere
});
```

Comment: when your validating, on error `return false;`

Comment: @jayharris `return false;` is overkill for this situation.

Comment: html5 validation, even one invalid field, will prevent the submit. you can make it valid with js to allow the submit, even call.submit() manually if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // validation code with script error somewhere
});
```